# How to add assets into the public folder in Nuxt 3 inside a module

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I've been using Nuxt 3 since its first release candidate and I really like it! I recently started creating modules for the framework and I've reached a roadblock

For a bit more context, I'm building a module to easily integrate `bootstrap-icons` with Nuxt 3, this is the code inside `module.ts`

```js
import { defineNuxtModule, addComponent, createResolver } from "@nuxt/kit";
import { readdirSync } from "fs";

// Module options TypeScript interface definition
export interface ModuleOptions {
  renderType: "inline" | "component";
}

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
  meta: {
    name: "nuxt-bootstrap-icons",
    configKey: "bootstrapIcons",
    compatibility: {
      nuxt: "^3.0.0",
    },
  },
  // Default configuration options of the Nuxt module
  defaults: { renderType: "inline" },
  async setup({ renderType }, { options: { css }, hook }) {
    const { resolve } = createResolver(import.meta.url);

    if (renderType === "inline") {
      css.push(
        resolve("../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css")
      );

      // hook("nitro:config", (configuration) => {
      //   configuration.publicAssets ||= [];
      //   configuration.publicAssets.push({
      //     dir: resolve("../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/fonts"),
      //     maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
      //     fallthrough: true,
      //   });
      // });

      addComponent({
        filePath: resolve("./runtime/BootstrapIcon.vue"),
        name: "BootstrapIcon",
      });
      return;
    } else if (renderType === "component") {
      const components = readdirSync(
        resolve("./runtime/components")
      ) as string[];
      for (const component of components) {
        addComponent({
          filePath: resolve("./runtime/components", component),
          name: `BootstrapIcon${component.split(".")[0]}`,
        });
      }
    }
  },
});
```

so the problem I'm experience is when I run `yarn dev:build`, it builds normally but I don't see the fonts for `bootstrap-icons`

This is the response before the code I commented out

```
Nuxi 3.6.0                                                                                                20:54:27
Nuxt 3.6.0 with Nitro 2.5.1                                                                               20:54:27
=============                                                                                             20:54:28

WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree.

You may find that it works just fine, or you may not.

SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=3.3.1 <5.1.0

YOUR TYPESCRIPT VERSION: 5.1.3

Please only submit bug reports when using the officially supported version.

=============
ℹ Building client...                                                                                      20:54:30
ℹ vite v4.3.9 building for production...                                                                  20:54:30
ℹ ✓ 87 modules transformed.                                                                               20:54:33
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/manifest.json                   2.26 kB │ gzip:  0.37 kB                              20:54:33
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-500.06915589.css    1.95 kB │ gzip:  0.73 kB                              20:54:33
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-404.d7252154.css    3.63 kB │ gzip:  1.12 kB                              20:54:33
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-500.6480bcf6.js     1.88 kB │ gzip:  0.99 kB                              20:54:33
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-404.99c8b07f.js     6.53 kB │ gzip:  2.90 kB                              20:54:33
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/entry.7719e6fd.js       102.74 kB │ gzip: 38.89 kB                              20:54:33
ℹ ✓ built in 3.19s                                                                                        20:54:33
✔ Client built in 3206ms                                                                                  20:54:33
ℹ Building server...                                                                                      20:54:33
ℹ vite v4.3.9 building SSR bundle for production...                                                       20:54:33
ℹ ✓ 45 modules transformed.                                                                               20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/entry-styles.126c66f4.mjs            0.08 kB                                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-styles.24bae852.mjs        0.15 kB                                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-styles.80b328d8.mjs        0.15 kB                                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/styles.mjs                                 0.65 kB                                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-e12b288f.js                    0.22 kB │ map:  5.33 kB                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/island-renderer-f70c2cce.js          1.05 kB │ map:  1.51 kB                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-styles-1.mjs-841ffe36.js   2.17 kB │ map:  0.12 kB                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-9b69f27b.js                3.10 kB │ map:  3.83 kB                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-styles-1.mjs-cea0a2e2.js   3.86 kB │ map:  0.12 kB                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-a3734834.js                9.75 kB │ map: 19.05 kB                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs                                26.31 kB │ map: 57.56 kB                    20:54:35
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/entry-styles-1.mjs-04ccc3c8.js      82.13 kB │ map:  0.11 kB                    20:54:35
ℹ ✓ built in 2.11s                                                                                        20:54:35
✔ Server built in 2115ms                                                                                  20:54:35
✔ Generated public playground/.output/public                                                        nitro 20:54:35
ℹ Building Nitro Server (preset: node-server)                                                       nitro 20:54:35
✔ Nitro server built                                                                                nitro 20:54:39
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/entry-styles.126c66f4.mjs (82.2 kB) (12.7 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/entry-styles.126c66f4.mjs.map (443 B) (267 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-404-a3734834.mjs (10 kB) (3.22 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-404-a3734834.mjs.map (8.06 kB) (2 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-404-styles.24bae852.mjs (3.98 kB) (1.25 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-404-styles.24bae852.mjs.map (404 B) (244 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-500-9b69f27b.mjs (3.31 kB) (1.45 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-500-9b69f27b.mjs.map (1.72 kB) (632 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-500-styles.80b328d8.mjs (2.28 kB) (867 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-500-styles.80b328d8.mjs.map (404 B) (244 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/island-renderer-f70c2cce.mjs (1.36 kB) (624 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/island-renderer-f70c2cce.mjs.map (940 B) (455 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/client.manifest.mjs (2.66 kB) (476 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/client.manifest.mjs.map (1.33 kB) (360 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs (26.3 kB) (7.38 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs.map (30.2 kB) (5.07 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/styles.mjs (724 B) (337 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/styles.mjs.map (461 B) (244 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/error-500.mjs (4.26 kB) (1.82 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/error-500.mjs.map (1.13 kB) (422 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs (10.5 kB) (3.27 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs.map (12.1 kB) (2.45 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/nitro/node-server.mjs (25.8 kB) (7.53 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/nitro/node-server.mjs.map (94.8 kB) (6.75 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/rollup/_virtual_head-static.mjs (301 B) (217 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/rollup/_virtual_head-static.mjs.map (111 B) (112 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/rollup/_virtual_spa-template.mjs (697 B) (449 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/rollup/_virtual_spa-template.mjs.map (112 B) (112 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/index.mjs (539 B) (283 B gzip)
  └─ playground/.output/server/package.json (1.31 kB) (494 B gzip)
Σ Total size: 2.84 MB (666 kB gzip)
✔ You can preview this build using node playground/.output/server/index.mjs                         nitro 20:54:39
✨  Done in 12.92s.
```

and this is the response after being commented out

```
Nuxi 3.6.0                                                                                                20:55:35
Nuxt 3.6.0 with Nitro 2.5.1                                                                               20:55:35
=============                                                                                             20:55:37

WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree.

You may find that it works just fine, or you may not.

SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=3.3.1 <5.1.0

YOUR TYPESCRIPT VERSION: 5.1.3

Please only submit bug reports when using the officially supported version.

=============
ℹ Building client...                                                                                      20:55:38
ℹ vite v4.3.9 building for production...                                                                  20:55:38
ℹ ✓ 87 modules transformed.                                                                               20:55:40
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/manifest.json                   2.26 kB │ gzip:  0.37 kB                              20:55:40
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-500.06915589.css    1.95 kB │ gzip:  0.73 kB                              20:55:40
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-404.d7252154.css    3.63 kB │ gzip:  1.12 kB                              20:55:40
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-500.6480bcf6.js     1.88 kB │ gzip:  0.99 kB                              20:55:40
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/error-404.99c8b07f.js     6.53 kB │ gzip:  2.90 kB                              20:55:40
ℹ .nuxt/dist/client/_nuxt/entry.7719e6fd.js       102.74 kB │ gzip: 38.89 kB                              20:55:40
ℹ ✓ built in 2.54s                                                                                        20:55:40
✔ Client built in 2551ms                                                                                  20:55:40
ℹ Building server...                                                                                      20:55:40
ℹ vite v4.3.9 building SSR bundle for production...                                                       20:55:40
ℹ ✓ 45 modules transformed.                                                                               20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/entry-styles.126c66f4.mjs            0.08 kB                                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-styles.24bae852.mjs        0.15 kB                                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-styles.80b328d8.mjs        0.15 kB                                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/styles.mjs                                 0.65 kB                                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/index-e12b288f.js                    0.22 kB │ map:  5.33 kB                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/island-renderer-f70c2cce.js          1.05 kB │ map:  1.51 kB                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-styles-1.mjs-841ffe36.js   2.17 kB │ map:  0.12 kB                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-500-9b69f27b.js                3.10 kB │ map:  3.83 kB                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-styles-1.mjs-cea0a2e2.js   3.86 kB │ map:  0.12 kB                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/error-404-a3734834.js                9.75 kB │ map: 19.05 kB                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs                                26.31 kB │ map: 57.56 kB                    20:55:43
ℹ .nuxt/dist/server/_nuxt/entry-styles-1.mjs-04ccc3c8.js      82.13 kB │ map:  0.11 kB                    20:55:43
ℹ ✓ built in 2.66s                                                                                        20:55:43
✔ Server built in 2719ms                                                                                  20:55:43
✔ Generated public playground/.output/public                                                        nitro 20:55:43
ℹ Building Nitro Server (preset: node-server)                                                       nitro 20:55:43
✔ Nitro server built                                                                                nitro 20:55:47
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/entry-styles.126c66f4.mjs (82.2 kB) (12.7 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/entry-styles.126c66f4.mjs.map (443 B) (267 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-404-a3734834.mjs (10 kB) (3.22 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-404-a3734834.mjs.map (8.06 kB) (2 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-404-styles.24bae852.mjs (3.98 kB) (1.25 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-404-styles.24bae852.mjs.map (404 B) (244 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-500-9b69f27b.mjs (3.31 kB) (1.45 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-500-9b69f27b.mjs.map (1.72 kB) (632 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-500-styles.80b328d8.mjs (2.28 kB) (867 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/error-500-styles.80b328d8.mjs.map (404 B) (244 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/island-renderer-f70c2cce.mjs (1.36 kB) (624 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/_nuxt/island-renderer-f70c2cce.mjs.map (940 B) (455 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/client.manifest.mjs (2.66 kB) (476 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/client.manifest.mjs.map (1.33 kB) (360 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs (26.3 kB) (7.38 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs.map (30.2 kB) (5.07 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/styles.mjs (724 B) (337 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/app/styles.mjs.map (461 B) (244 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/error-500.mjs (4.26 kB) (1.82 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/error-500.mjs.map (1.13 kB) (422 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs (10.5 kB) (3.27 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs.map (12.1 kB) (2.45 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/nitro/node-server.mjs (25.3 kB) (7.4 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/nitro/node-server.mjs.map (94.8 kB) (6.75 kB gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/rollup/_virtual_head-static.mjs (301 B) (217 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/rollup/_virtual_head-static.mjs.map (111 B) (112 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/rollup/_virtual_spa-template.mjs (697 B) (449 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/chunks/rollup/_virtual_spa-template.mjs.map (112 B) (112 B gzip)
  ├─ playground/.output/server/index.mjs (539 B) (283 B gzip)
  └─ playground/.output/server/package.json (1.31 kB) (494 B gzip)
Σ Total size: 2.84 MB (666 kB gzip)
✔ You can preview this build using node playground/.output/server/index.mjs                         nitro 20:55:47
✨  Done in 13.09s.
```

**Note:** the code without comments actually places the font files inside the public directory but when I run

`node playground/.output/server/index.mjs`

I get a box when a font fails loading as seen below:

[image: Font not loading]

When I inspect inside the DevTools (inside the network tab) I discover that the font references inside the `bootstrap-icons.min.css` file is appended a random hash, which when I build the demo the fonts which are added don't get appended any hash

[image: Network devtools]

Please can you help, cause I don't know what to do